# How to include a root SSL certificate as a resource in a J2ME application?

Tags: java, ssl, mobile, https, java-me

I'm writing a J2ME application that make HTTPS requests on a phone with outdated root SSL certificates
and I wanted to ask is there a way to include a root SSL certificate as a resource in the application and let The HttpsConnection API validate against this root certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You can't supply certificates with your application for working with default API. But you can use libraries, which can replaces this API, for example: https://github.com/rotsenmarcello/mhc

If you want install root certificate, this question is very device-specific and have no single answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about a specific SSL certificate you just need to install on the phone, to be used by the phone browser, I think there's a way do to it with JavaME:

1. Include the certificate inside the JAR.
2. Code a simple webserver that serves the cerfiticate file, and start it.
3. Call `platformRequest("http://127.0.0.1");`

This should theoretically open a new native browser and the user downloads and installs the certificate.